# jquery ajax history and bookmarking plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

There are plugins for handling history and bookmarking like: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history. Somehow it doesn't look as a complete solution. For example, on one page you might have a filter that consists of several checkboxes, text boxes etc. You would like your page history functionality to update all those controls and to update url when value of some of those controls is changed. With the jquery history plugin, you would have to write all that code (even parsing of the hash value from url). Is there some more complete solution for this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ben Alman has recently released a fantastic plugin to handle things related to the questions you are asking. It is called [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) (for Back Button and Query). It has excellent [documentation](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html), full [unit tests](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/unit/) and is alot more up to date than the antiquated jQuery History plugin. I especially like the onhashchange work that he did. (5 Stars. would do business with again A+++)

Comment: did something like that myself > https://github.com/lautr/asfar works with "normal" urls

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try this jQuery History plugin: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js
It provides cross browser support, binding to hashes, overloading hashes, all the rest.

There is also a Ajax extension for it, allowing it to easily upgrade your webpage into a proper Ajax application: http://browserstate.github.com/history.js/demo/

This is the solution chosen by such sites as http://wbhomes.com.au/ and http://gatesonline.com.au/stage/public/

Overall it is well documented, supported and feature rich. It's also won a bounty question here [How to show Ajax requests in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url/3276206#3276206)