# Anchor on single page website

Tags: html

This is an issue regarding, http://www.mccaffreyhautecouture.com/
I am unable to create an external link where the viewer is brought to a specific page within the website. On landing, the viewer must always enter by the landing/main slide page.

This was a purchased template and the entire website is coded in a single index.html file.

My client would like their Pinterest images to link directly to the source or gallery. 
Is this at all possible?

I greatly appreciate any assistance.
Thank you, 
Stanley Ounarom

Comment: I had a look. I couldn't find the pinterst images. give us a clue where they are and what they should link too.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to provide you a direct link but if you go to Collections > Bridal > Blanc et Noir, all of the images in that gallery have a 'Pin It' button in the caption when you click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was written using AJAX to pull in content. The URL doesn't change when nav is clicked, which makes it impossible to link to a specific page w/in the site. The site will need to be further developed to allow for this functionality.

This may help:
[jquery ajax history and bookmarking plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605561/jquery-ajax-history-and-bookmarking-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the link Andrew. This looks to be a bit over my head, I may have to find a programmer to fix this issue!

Comment: Good luck! Sorry there's not an easy solution.